# Why do the records get deleted in an access database when I open the file in access?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I'm developing a simple database app in visual studio (c# for Windows) using an access backend.

That's all fine until I try to open the database file from within access, when all the reocords get deleted.

Could anyone explain why this is please?

Comment: Are you saying they're deleted or go missing?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "Access back end." You have a Jet back end.

Comment: Go tell Microsoft e.g. "create a 'front-end/back-end solution' that uses a front-end Access database (.mdb) running on each user's computer that contains linked tables that connect to a back-end Access database (.mdb) on a network file server" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139930.aspx).

Comment: e.g. 2: "This paper is for Access developers preparing to migrate their Access back end to SQL Server 2000" (http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2000/Deploy/accessmigration.mspx).

Comment: e.g. 3: "In the Create Back-end Database dialog box, type a name for the back-end Access database file in the File name box" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/835416).

Comment: ...and there's plenty more exmaples of Microsoft using the generic term 'Access' to encompass features of Jet. Go pick on Microsoft!

Comment: Seeing this very late: I frequently do criticize MS for obfuscating the difference between Access and Jet/ACE. That's no excuse for a developer not using precise terminology.

Comment: If you like precise terminology, why aren't you using the term 'Jet Red'? Also, you seem to have completely missed the point: we need a collective term to refer to Jet, ACE and any other name the Access Team may invent in the future for the Access application's default engine (don't forget that MSDE and Jet Blue were near misses). So you've taken it upon yourself to invent 'Jet/ACE' -- no big deal. Microsoft have chosen the term 'Access Database Engine' -- no big deal. So please don't admonish folk on Stackoverflow for preferring Microsoft's arbitrary terminology over yours.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the database to your solution?  Select it and check the Copy Local (aka Copy to Output Directory) setting in the Properties window.  Make sure it isn't set to Copy Always,

Comment: +1; Yep, this has bitten me before.  Certainly good advice, even if it doesn't turn out to be the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information. You say that when you open the database from within access, "all the records get deleted". The way the question is phrased implies that some process is running as part of opening the database, e.g., an autoexecute macro. Do you really know that is what is happening? Or are you really just saying that "when I open the database file from access, ***the records are not there***". If the latter, then something is happening along the lines of what cletus suggests.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I don't know if the original poster is still around, but something that didn't occur to me at the time I originally read the question was that perhaps the C# app is using a transaction to insert the data and is not committing it. If that were the case, the data would be visible in the C# app and would not be there when you opened the file in Access. On the other hand, the data wouldn't be there in a new session of the C# app, either, so this might not be the issue.